# Is there consistency per connection setting in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to change consistency per connection or even transaction in MongoDB? 
For example, we have a Mongo cluster 6 nodes running across 2 Data centers (3 nodes in each DC) and we have async mode. I get the transaction from the client that is very important and want to finish it only after the data will be transferred on 4 nodes in the cluster. 
I got another transaction and I need a performance so I am happy enough when information is saved in just 1 node. 
I know I can configure such thing for the whole cluster but I cannot find is there a way to change settings based on connection/transaction. 
Here is such feature in PostgreSQL https://www.compose.com/articles/postgresql-and-per-connection-write-consistency-settings/

I am rather new to MongoDB so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can set read/write concerns per transaction: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#read-concern-write-concern-read-preference

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for.